# What is the fastest way to update sql table?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# app which allows the user to update some columns in a DB. My problem is that I have 300.000 records in the DB, and just updating 50.000 took 30 mins. Can I do something to speed things up?

My update query looks like this:

```
UPDATE SET UM = 'UM', Code = 'Code' WHERE Material = 'MaterialCode'.
```

My only unique constrain is Material. I read the file the user selects, and put the data in a datatable, and then I go row by row, and update the corresponding material in the DB

Comment: Help us out by showing your SQL statement(s).

Comment: Can you post the update query and the schema?

Comment: Do you have a lot of Unique Constraints?

Comment: Besides the other recommendations it may also be helpful to see the C# code that runs the update. It's possible that you're performing the updates in less-than optimal fashion on the client side.

Comment: I would also add to other comments: during these 30 mins, does the cpu/memory go too high ? because depending on the query, you may have a bottleneck there.

Comment: My update query looks like this:

UPDATE SET UM = 'UM', Code = 'Code' WHERE Material = 'MaterialCode'.

My only unique constrain is Material. I read the file the user selects, and put the data in a datatable, and then I go row by row, and update the corresponding material in the DB.

Comment: @RoxanaDinca: There's your issue. Why not apply the UPDATE command directly against the database? You are updating RBAR-style from the client (row by agonizing row.) The process could not be any less efficient IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Limit the number of indexes in your database especially if your application updates data very frequently.This is because each index takes up disk space and slow the adding, deleting, and updating of rows, you should create new indexes only after analyze the uses of the data, the types and frequencies of queries performed, and how your queries will use the new indexes.

In many cases, the speed advantages of creating the new indexes outweigh the disadvantages of additional space used and slowly rows modification. However, avoid using redundant indexes, create them only when it is necessary. For read-only table, the number of indexes can be increased.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use non clustered index on the table if the update is frequent.
2. Use clustered index on the table if the updates/inserts are not frequent.
3. C# code may not be a problem , your update statement is important. Where clause of the update statement is the place to lookout for.  You need to have some indexed column in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing, is the field material, indexed? And also, is the where clause, needed to be on a field with a varchar value? Can't it be an integer valued field?

Performance will be better if you filter on fields having integers and not strings. Not sure if this is possible for you.